# Meaning of error numbers in Python exceptions

Tags: python, errno, overflowexception

Catching Python's `OverflowError` after some dumb calculation, I checked the error's `args` and saw it's a tuple containing an integer as its first coordinate. I assume this is some kind of error number (`errno`). However, I could not find any documentation or reference for it.

Example:

```
try:
    1e4**100
except OverflowError as ofe:
    print ofe.args

## prints '(34, 'Numerical result out of range')'
```

Do you know what `34` means in this context? Do you know other possible error numbers for this exception?

Comment: For the record, 1E400 is not representable as a [double](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) which is the usual internal representation of Python's float.

Comment: For another record, `1e400` equals `inf` in python 2.7 (as `math.isinf(1e400)` shows).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a module in the standard library called [`errno`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/errno.html):

> This module makes available standard errno system symbols. The value
>   of each symbol is the corresponding integer value. The names and
>   descriptions are borrowed from linux/include/errno.h, which should be
>   pretty all-inclusive.

`/usr/include/linux/errno.h` includes `/usr/include/asm/errno.h` that includes `/usr/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h`.

```
me@my_pc:~$ cat /usr/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h | grep 34
#define ERANGE      34  /* Math result not representable */
```

Now we know that the 34 error code stands for ERANGE.

`1e4**100` is processed with [`float_pow` function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/7ec8c4555772/Objects/floatobject.c#l809) from [Object/floatobject.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/7ec8c4555772/Objects/floatobject.c). Partial source code of that function:

```c
static PyObject *
float_pow(PyObject *v, PyObject *w, PyObject *z)
{
    // 107 lines omitted

    if (errno != 0) {
        /* We do not expect any errno value other than ERANGE, but
         * the range of libm bugs appears unbounded.
         */
        PyErr_SetFromErrno(errno == ERANGE ? PyExc_OverflowError :
                             PyExc_ValueError);
        return NULL;
    }
    return PyFloat_FromDouble(ix);
}
```

So, `1e4**100` causes ERANGE error (resulting in `PyExc_OverflowError`) and then the higher level `OverflowError` exception raises.

Comment: Oh, that's nice. I believe I have the exact same output as you have.