# Why does Python's argparse use an error code of 2 for SystemExit?

Tags: python, argparse, errno

When I give Python's argparse input it doesn't like, it raises a SystemExit with a code of 2, which [seems to mean "No such file or directory"](https://docs.python.org/2/library/errno.html). Why use this error code?

```
import argparse
import errno

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('arg')

try:
    parser.parse_args([])
except SystemExit as se:
    print("Got error code {} which is {} in errno"
        .format(se.code, errno.errorcode[se.code]))
```

produces this output:

```
usage: se.py [-h] arg
se.py: error: too few arguments
Got error code 2 which is ENOENT in errno
```

Comment: Exit codes have different meanings for different systems. The `errno` codes are an entirely *different* standard.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I didn't realize that. Is there any info out there about the standard (if any) argparse is using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meaning of error numbers in Python exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955720/meaning-of-error-numbers-in-python-exceptions)

Comment: @frostnational: that is about `errno` error codes, **not** about why `argparse` uses 2 as the exit code. You are making the same mistake as the OP here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are confusing [C `errno` *error* codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errno.h) with a process [exit status](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status); the two concepts are entirely unrelated.

Exit status values [have no official standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101957/are-there-any-standard-exit-status-codes-in-linux), but by convention 2 is taken to mean *Incorrect usage*; this is the [exit code used by Bash built-ins](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html), for example.

The [`os` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.EX_OK) exposes `os.EX_*` constants that represent the `sysexit.h` constants used by many POSIX systems. [`os.EX_USAGE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.EX_USAGE) is exit code 64 and could be used as well, although `argparse` doesn't actually use this constant as it is only available on UNIX systems while `argparse` needs to work on Windows and other platforms too.

Comment: I agree with most that you write, but ironically, on the TLDP site you linked it is stated that error code 2 "should therefore be avoided for user-specified exit parameters". Since it is called "Misuse of shell builtins", I think that this is also relevant to Python interpreters, because they are not shell builtins.
So I would not call it a really established convention (for example, `rsync` uses error code 1 for CL argument errors, `git` - 129 and `wget`, indeed, 2).